# Error: JMSCC5007: Use of JMS2.0 API "createContext()" s not supported

Tags: java, jms, mq

```
    try {
        // Create a connection factory
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

        // Set the properties
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

        // Create JMS objects
        context = cf.createContext();
        destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

        producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(destination, message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

        consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
        String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

        System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

        recordSuccess();
    } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
        recordFailure(jmsex);
    }
```

while running this code with all the required details, I am getting the below error:

```
Error: JMSCC5007: Use of JMS2.0 API "createContext()" is not supported with this instance of this connection. Only connections with a correct type of connection can support using this JMS2.0 API.
```

For some queues this code is working but for others this is giving the above error.  Is it because of channel not started?

Comment: The error message indicates exactly what the problem is - you're using a JMS 2.0 API call on a connection which doesn't support it. A quick search for `JMSCC5007` finds [the IBM documentation on this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q120080_.htm).

Comment: How do you connect to the queue manager?   If it is via a SVRCONN channel is it the same for both working or non-working?

Comment: createContext API is part of JMS 2.0 specification. JMS 2.0 support was added in IBM MQ v8.0. If your application is connecting to pre MQ v.8 queue manager, then I think "JMSCC5007" error will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This very much looks like the underlying JMS provider does not implement JMS v2.0 (for the queues where it fails).

You can circumvent this issue by using the `createConnection()` method instead of `createContext()`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But this code works for one queue and is not working for another queue. I am not able to understand the reason for that.

Comment: So what is the version of that "another" queue manager? MQ v8 or above?

Comment: Here you can find the code for,- `createConnection()` usage, under the link,- https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms20.html